# Castle Windsor: TypedFactoryFacility, Generic factories and Potential lifestyle mismatches

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

I am using the [TypeFactoryFacility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility.ashx) with a generic factory to avoid having the container instantiate components until they are required. The generic factory looks like this:

```
public interface IGenericFactory<T> {
   T Create();
   void Release(T dummyComponent);
}
```

Later I use it in the following fashion:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IGenericFactory<IUtilityService>>().AsFactory());
container.Register(
    Component.For<IUtilityService>().ImplementedBy<UtilityService>()
        .OnCreate(WireUpAttibutes).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

Then I use `IGenericFactory<IUtilityService>` as a constructor parameter and call `Create()` when I need to use the component. In the context of the web application I am dealing with it is very important that the UtilityService is bound to the web request (which is why it is registered with `LifeStyle.PerWebRequest`)

When I look at the containers debugger view "Potential lifestyle mismatches" I get a message:

> Component 'IGenericFactory' with lifestyle Singleton*
>   depends on 'TypedFactoryInterceptor' with lifestyle Transient This
>   kind of dependency is usually not desired and may lead to various
>   kinds of bugs.

If I register the generic factory:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IGenericFactory<IUtilityService>>()
    .AsFactory().LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Then the message goes away, but I wonder if I am losing out because now Windsor will create a factory for every web request. This will be cheaper than resolving the IUtilityService but it would be nice to only have to use a singleton factory as this factory does not have any dependencies. (that are created by me)

Is it an issue to register components as such?
Will the factory will resolve the component IUtilityService per web request?

Comment: Maybe instead of using this generic factory you better look into Lazy<> see: http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Whats-New-In-Windsor-3&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: That Lazy<> implementation seems to be doing the thing I am looking for. I would still like to know the answer to this question however.

Comment: you will get this message for every singleton that uses (depends on) transient interceptors. Since the factory facility creates a (transient) interceptor you will get the message. IMHO you can safely ignore it.